# How to check if two elements are toggled using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, visible

I want to check if `#kndpopup` and `#guildinfo` elements are toggled, then after clicking `#knd` I want them both to go back to being untoggled.

Currently if I click `#knd` the `#kndpopup` toggles, then when I click `#knd` again the `#kndpopup` becomes untoggled, as intended. However, when I toggle `#kndpopup` and then toggle `#guildinfo`, which is an identical popup that sits over `#kndpopup` to hide it (like another page with information), I can't untoggle both `#kndpopup` and `#guildinfo` with the `#knd` button, it just toggles between them instead of closing them. How can I fix this? I have both elements set to `display: none` in the CSS.

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#knd").click(function() {
    $("#kndpopup").fadeToggle();

});

$(".info").click(function() {
    $("#kndpopup").fadeToggle();
    $("#guildinfo").fadeToggle();
});
```

**EDITED CODE:**

```
$("#knd").click(function() {
    $("#kndpopup").fadeToggle();

    if($('#guildinfo').is(':visible')){
        $("#guildinfo").fadeToggle();
}
```

This sorta works, but when `#guildinfo` is toggled and I click on `#knd`, it toggles back to `#kndpopup` when I click on `#knd`, how do I fix this?

**3RD ATTEMPT:**

```
$("#knd").click(function() {
    $("#kndpopup").fadeToggle();    

    if($("#guildinfo").is(':visible')){
        $("#guildinfo").fadeToggle();
    }

    else if($("#kndpopup").is(":hidden") && ("#guildinfo").is(":visible")) {
    return;
    }

});
```

It still doesn't work the way I want it to, please help.

Comment: Try triggering their click event `$("#kndpopup").click();` and it will untoggle/toggle.

Comment: That makes no sense, I don't want to click on the `#kndpopup` for it to untoggle? :o

Comment: So your question is that you want to check if element is visible or hidden and than do action accordingly? than check the answer below.

Comment: Correct. That answer works, just gotta fix so that it doesn't `fadeToggle()` back to the `#kndpopup` before closing..

Comment: Instead of fadeToggle, try using `fadeTo` or `fadeIn` with `fadeOut` so you have more control.

Comment: Without a demo it will be hard to really understand what you want.

Comment: The second else if bit in 3RD attempt code is totally useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer does the trick:

```
$("#knd").click(function () {

    var KND = $("#kndpopup");
    var GUILDINFO = $("#guildinfo");

    if ((KND).is(':visible')) {
        $(KND).fadeOut();
    } 

    else if ((GUILDINFO).is(':visible')) {
        $(GUILDINFO).fadeOut();
        $(KND).fadeOut();
    } 

    else {
        $(KND).fadeIn();
    }

});

$(".info").click(function () {
    $("#kndpopup").fadeToggle();
    $("#guildinfo").fadeToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this if statement to change the behaviour of the toggle.

```
if($('#kndpopup').is(':visible')){
    //This will run if the element is visible
}
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the edited code and the problem that followed with it, is there a simple solution to the problem?